# Interchanging limit and expectation for irreducible Markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

If you have an irreducible Markov chain initialised in a state $k$ then the ergodic theorem on Markov chains says that the long-run frequencies converge to an invariant probability distribution $\pi_i$, which is independent of $k$. If $n(i)$ is the amount of time spent in state $i$ (measured in the discrete time), which is the correct statement,
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}E \left[\frac{n(i)}{N} \right] = \pi_i$$
or
$$E \left[ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{n(i)}{N} \right] = \pi_i$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ergodic theorem actually gives almost sure convergence.  So what you have is actually:

$$ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \frac{n(i)}{N} = \pi_i \quad \text{a.s.}$$

By Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, this implies the first; the second follows by simply taking expectation of both sides of the above.